# Correcting directory structure in Subversion

Tags: svn

My subversion repository is structured as:

```
/project1   (this contains the trunk)
/project1-tags
/project2
/project2-tags
...
```

I want to correct it to:

```
/project1
    /trunk
    /tags
/project2
    /trunk
    /tags
...
```

How can I do it without messing up the current tags which are already present?
I'm using TortoiseSVN client and Subversion server, both on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Checkout the complete directory structure on your local workspace (I don't recommend performing any operation on the repo directly)
- Create the empty folders for `tags` and `trunk` under the project directories. (Commit)
- Now, open the directory whose content you'd like to move to a new location, e.g., `project1-tags`. Select all the content,  hold the **right-mouse** button and drag them to the new location.

You will get a option list like this:

[image: SVN Move]

Select the desired option and you're done.

** No History is lost in this process!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think need to copy each branch/tag with TortoiseSVN branch/tag menu to proper locations and then remove old ones. Not sure that there is simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for the Repository Browser.

Before you begin, make sure everything is committed.

Fire up the repo-browser by right-clicking any file or directory that's checked out from the repository you want to change.
Then simply drag /project1-tags into /project1. Once the folder's been moved, right-click it and select rename.

When you're done moving and renaming the folders, delete the local copy and check it out again (if you had anything checked out from a folder that got moved, that is).

[Repository Browser manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-repobrowser.html)